# git fail "fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git

try to get the code from the following project
http://git.webvm.net/?p=npsimple;a=summary

tried in git bash:

```
git clone git://git.webvm.net/npsimple
```

but then I got:

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

something wrong with the server or I am not using git in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it too and got the same problem, the more likely reason is that the access is not public and that you are not allowed to copy that repo. It is the message that people usually get from gitosis when they do not have access.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right id_rsa (private key) in your .ssh folder corresponding to the account you are using for your git repository.